# Revived man in world of women

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for old (paperback) book where men are revivified from dug up bones in a cemetery and then treated to make them stupid so that they can work in a factory.

One escapes aided by a woman supervisor who revives our victim while drunk, and wants him capable (of sex) and hence neglects to "dumb" him. She passes out and he has the opportunity to escapes her house in the morning, hiding in the fields.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Re query above, the woman supervisor revives our victim while drunk, and wants him capable, so does not "dumb" him, passes out, and he escapes her house in the morning, hiding in the fields. Cannot think of any other clue, except my copy at the time was a paperback, which could have been of any age.

Comment: When did you read this book? How old is old?

Comment: Sorry for late pickup. Read it twenty years ago, but it is from the 50/60s at a guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be Wilson Tucker's tongue-in-cheek novel *Resurrection Days* from 1981. I can't remember much about it & I have been unable to find a detailed description, but it does involve a man who dies in the 20th century and is revived thousands of years later in a society dominated by women. Most revived men are drones, but he is a 'variant', one who has self-awareness (possibly for sexual purposes). He escapes and causes havoc.

Comment: That must be the right one. I found this detailed review: http://mporcius.blogspot.com/2016/07/resurrection-days-by-wilson-tucker.html

Comment: Another review https://schlock-value.com/2015/06/07/resurrection-days/

Comment: Thanks for that. Yup, as soon as I looked it up I recognised the cover image. It turns out that Tucker was one of the quiet giants of SF. Year of the Quiet Sun, The Long Loud Silence, Ice and Iron. He wrote some high quality novels. Help much appreciated.

Comment: I agree. Don't forget the Lincoln Hunters!